# Is there any readily available concept/topic tree?

Tags: knowledge-representation

I am looking for dataset in tree structure that captures the hierarchy of concepts.
For example, something like,

```
                         Entertainment
                   Movies           Sports
              Comedy  Thriller   cricket football
   charlie chaplin              sachin       messy
```

Comment: Not sure if it will construct that specific tree for you, but have you checked http://conceptnet.io/ to see if it is suitable for your purpose? Perhaps explain a bit more about what you need this tree for - or traits that it should have - as there are lots of ways to break down knowledge like this. Typically a simple tree structure is very poor at capturing how language is used inpractice

Comment: @NeilSlater I am looking for this tree for say someone subscribes to a topic called sports, I would probably want them to be automatically subscribed to all kinds of sport, like cricket, football etc.

Comment: The issue for you then is that there is no such tree in general for natural language. It depends on your problem domain. Shopping will be different to media consumption. If your topic list is small enough, then the classic way to do this in e.g. web site design is a "card sort" https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/card-sorting.html - I suggest that you add your use case to the question, as you really are looking for a simplified tree for your domain. It's probably not an AI topic, unless you want to ask about constructing the tree from something more complex